# Can you set the connection of an Exec SQL task through a dtsConfig file

Tags: configuration, ssis

Can you set the connection of an SSIS `Exec SQL` task through a dtsConfig file?

I have a SSIS package with an `Exec SQL` task, with it's `Connection` property set to a OLE Db `Connection Manager` ... it runs fine in Visual Studio.

Created a package configuration with the connection string of the connection manager, but when I try and run it from DTEXEC, I get the errors ... `The specified module could not be found` against the connection manager, and then ... `Failed to acquire connection "ZZZ". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection`

Comment: Have you verified that if you hard code this connection it works OK in DTEXEC. The error may just mean that the connection has loaded from the cofig OK but it can't connect (no driver, no connectivity etc.) is there any more info in the log?

Comment: @ElectricLlama Running DTEXEC with hard coded values, user id + password, integrated security, config file / no config file ... none work. Even tried in Execute Package Utility and still no luck. In Visual Studio with both userid+password and integrated security, works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No but yes ;)

You cannot directly change the connection manager through a configuration. That property isn't exposed.

What you *can* do is use your configuration to change the ConnectionString property on an existing Connection Manager that the Execute SQL Task uses thereby changing the connection for an Execute SQL Task at run-time via configuration.

If you need a more detailed walkthrough, I can probably generate some basic biml

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think this is what I've already done, my Exec SQL task is using an existing Connection Manager. But when I try running the package with DTEXEC and setting the configuration via the /CONFIG parameter, I get the above errors  :-(